# How can I change the notation of a matrix?

Tags: python

I'm editing a program, that program gives me as a result a sparse matrix

The matrix, with this notation

```
Y =   

  (0, 0)        -17.3611111111j
  (3, 0)        17.3611111111j
  (7, 1)        16j
  (1, 1)        -16j
  (2, 2)        -17.0648464164j
  (5, 2)        17.0648464164j
  (8, 3)        (-1.36518771331+11.6040955631j)
  (3, 3)        (3.30737896203-39.3088887261j)
  (0, 3)        17.3611111111j
  (4, 3)        (-1.94219124871+10.5106820519j)
  (4, 4)        (3.22420038714-15.8409270142j)
  (3, 4)        (-1.94219124871+10.5106820519j)
  (5, 4)        (-1.28200913842+5.58824496236j)
  (5, 5)        (2.43709661931-32.1538618051j)
  (2, 5)        17.0648464164j
  (4, 5)        (-1.28200913842+5.58824496236j)
  (6, 5)        (-1.15508748089+9.78427042636j)
  (6, 6)        (2.77220995414-23.3032490233j)
  (5, 6)        (-1.15508748089+9.78427042636j)
  (7, 6)        (-1.61712247325+13.6979785969j)
  (7, 7)        (2.80472685254-35.4456131302j)
  (6, 7)        (-1.61712247325+13.6979785969j)
  (8, 7)        (-1.18760437929+5.97513453331j)
  (1, 7)        16j
  (8, 8)        (2.5527920926-17.3382300964j)
  (7, 8)        (-1.18760437929+5.97513453331j)
  (3, 8)        (-1.36518771331+11.6040955631j)
```

I want to get a matrix in the normal way

```
x =      np.array ([[-17.3611111111j,   0,  0,  17.3611111111j, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
                    [0, -16j,      0,     0,    0,  0,  0,  16j,    0],
                    [0, 0,     -17.0648464164j,   0,    0,  17.0648464164j, 0,  0,  0],
                    [17.3611111111j,    0,  0,  (3.30737896203-39.3088887261j),     (-1.94219124871+10.5106820519j),       0,      0,      0,      (-1.36518771331+11.6040955631j)],
                    [0, 0,  0,  (-1.94219124871+10.5106820519j),  (3.22420038714-15.8409270142j),   (-1.28200913842+5.58824496236j),    0,     0,       0],
                    [0, 0,  17.0648464164j, 0,      (-1.28200913842+5.58824496236j),       (2.43709661931-32.1538618051j),     (-1.15508748089+9.78427042636j),   0,       0    ],
                    [0, 0,  0,  0,      0   ,   (-1.15508748089+9.78427042636j),       (2.77220995414-23.3032490233j),    (-1.61712247325+13.6979785969j),    0 ],
                    [0, 16j,    0,  0,  0,  0,  (-1.61712247325+13.6979785969j),    (2.80472685254-35.4456131302j),   (-1.18760437929+5.97513453331j)],
                    [0, 0,     0,     (-1.36518771331+11.6040955631j),    0,       0,   0,  (-1.18760437929+5.97513453331j),    (2.5527920926-17.3382300964j)]])
```

How can I transform the first matrix to the second?

Comment: How did you get the first format in the first place? I've never seen it. Edit: aha, https://cmdlinetips.com/2018/03/sparse-matrices-in-python-with-scipy/ looks like your answer.

Comment: @taurus05 sorry, saw your edit, but we can't be sure until OP says whether it's a CSC or a COO sparse matrix, so I just replaced it with what we know it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to convert a sparse matrix from whatever format it is in, from `help(scipy.sparse)`:

```
   bsr_matrix - Block Sparse Row matrix
   coo_matrix - A sparse matrix in COOrdinate format
   csc_matrix - Compressed Sparse Column matrix
   csr_matrix - Compressed Sparse Row matrix
   dia_matrix - Sparse matrix with DIAgonal storage
   dok_matrix - Dictionary Of Keys based sparse matrix
   lil_matrix - Row-based linked list sparse matrix
```

in which case you just need to convert it into an array:

```
x = Y.toarray()
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I wanted